# How to atomically access multiple things that might be held by the same lock(s)?

Tags: multithreading, rust, locking

I have a big grid which multiple threads access simultaneously. I have it divided into regions, each of which is independently locked. I want to be able to have atomic operations that operate on specified sets of points, which may or may not be part of the same region.

What I have now includes:

```
pub struct RwGrid<T>{
    width : usize,
    height : usize,
    region_size : usize,
    regions : [RwLock<Vec<T>>; TOTAL_REGIONS]
}

impl<T: Copy + Colored> Grid<T> for RwGrid<T>{
    ...
    fn set_if<F>(&self, p : Point, f : F, value : T) -> bool where
        F : Fn(T) -> bool{
            let (region_index, index_in_region) = self.map_coordinates(p);
            let mut region = self.regions[region_index].write().unwrap();
            let pre_existing = region[index_in_region];
            if f(pre_existing){
                region[index_in_region] = value;
                true
            } else {false}
        }
    ...
}
```

Where `map_coordinates` is a helper function that maps Cartesian coordinates onto the index of the appropriate region, and the index of the given point within that region.

My goal is (among other things) a variant of that `set_if` function that atomically looks at a set of points, rather than a single point (specifically, it would look at the nine points making up the immediate neighborhood of a given point.) This set of points might be from the same region, or might come from multiple regions. Further, the locks need to be acquired in a particular order, or deadlock may be possible.

The atomicity requirement is important to note. If it helps, imagine you're trying to sometimes color points red, with the invariant that no red point may be adjacent to another red point. If two threads non-atomically read the neighborhood of the point they're considering, they may interleave, both checking that the other's target point is currently black, then setting two adjacent points red.

I don't know how to abstract over this. I can easily find the regions for a set of points, or for a single point I can acquire the lock and operate on it, but I've been beating my head on how to acquire a set of locks and then operate on points using the appropriate lock, without having enormous  amounts of hard-coded boiler plate.

To illustrate the problem, here's a variant of `set_if` that looks at just two points, and sets one of them based on a condition that depends on both:

```
fn set_if_2<F>(&self, p1 : Point, p2 : Point, f : F, value : T) -> bool where
        F : Fn(T, T) -> bool{
            let (region_index_1, index_in_region_1) = self.map_coordinates(p1);
            let (region_index_2, index_in_region_2) = self.map_coordinates(p2);
            if (region_index_1 == region_index_2){
                let mut region = self.regions[region_index_1].write().unwrap();
                let pre_existing_1 = region[index_in_region_1];
                let pre_existing_2 = region[index_in_region_2];
                if f(pre_existing_1, pre_existing_2){
                    region[index_in_region_1] = value;
                    true
                } else {false}
            } else {
                let mut region1 = self.regions[region_index_1].write().unwrap();
                let region2 = self.regions[region_index_2].write().unwrap();
                let pre_existing_1 = region1[index_in_region_1];
                let pre_existing_2 = region2[index_in_region_2];
                if f(pre_existing_1, pre_existing_2){
                    region1[index_in_region_1] = value;
                    true
                } else {false}
            }
        }
```

This code has two branches based on whether or not the points belong to the same region (and thus need one lock) or different regions (each with their own lock.) As you can imagine, expanding that pattern out to nine different points that might belong to many different configurations of region would be painful and wrong.

So far I have two ideas and they both sound bad:

1. Have a function that returns a `Vec<RwLockWriteGuard<T>>` and a structure which holds indexes into that vector each point should use. (So if all points come from the same region, the `Vec` would be one element long and each point would map to `0`).
2. Have the data actually live in a single unsafe `Vec` with no locks (I'm not even sure how to do that), but have "fake" locks corresponding to regions, and code the `Region` module so that points are only accessed after the corresponding lock has been grabbed. One chunk of code could then recognize and acquire the appropriate locks, but that would be independent of subsequently reading or writing to the points.

Are either of those ideas workable? Is there a better way to approach this?

EDIT: Some more code:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
pub struct Point(pub usize, pub usize);

fn map_coordinates(&self, p : Point) -> (usize, usize){
        let Point(x, y) = self.fix(p);
        let (region_width, region_height) = (self.width / REGIONS_PER_DIMENSION, self.height/REGIONS_PER_DIMENSION);
        let (target_square_x, target_square_y) = (x/region_width, y/region_height);
        let target_square_i = target_square_y * REGIONS_PER_DIMENSION + target_square_x;
        let (x_in_square, y_in_square) = (x % region_width, y % region_width);
        let index_in_square = y_in_square * region_width + x_in_square; 
        (target_square_i, index_in_square)
    }

fn fix(&self, p: Point) -> Point{
       let Point(x, y) = p;
       Point(modulo(x as i32, self.width), modulo(y as i32, self.height))
}

#[inline(always)]
pub fn modulo(a: i32, b: usize) -> usize {
    (((a % b as i32) + b as i32) % b as i32) as usize
}
```

One thing to note is that the wrapping behavior (which is enabled by the `fix` function above) slightly complicates avoiding deadlocks. Points will often be accessed by compass direction, like asking for the northern neighbor of a point. Because the grid wraps, if you always lock in order by compass direction - like, "Northern neighbor, then center, then southern" - you can get a deadlocked cycle. Another way of phrasing this is that if you access Points by the order they're specified in the request, rather than by the order they exist in the grid, you can get cycles.

Comment: I only skimmed the question at the moment, but you may be interested in a "re-entrant lock" (an example can be found in [the parking-lot crate](https://docs.rs/parking_lot/latest/parking_lot/type.ReentrantMutex.html)), however that doesn't grant write access since it could be abused to violate Rust's referential constraints.

Comment: @kmdreko That might be what I'm looking for. I don't think it completely trivializes my problem, though, partially because I also have to control the order in which the locks are acquired to avoid potential deadlocks.

Comment: Can you provide the definitions for `map_coordinates` and `Point` so I can try a few things? Also, what ordering exactly do you need? Left-to-right, top-to-bottom?

Comment: @PitaJ Added those in. As for ordering, any set ordering is fine - the complication there is that a lot of the code is based around compass direction, but the grid wraps. If you look at the `Neighborhood` struct which I also edited in, the Northern neighbor point might actually be on the southern edge of the grid. Thus if you always lock North, then Center, then South, relative to some point, you might get a cycle. So long as you're locking by objective rather than relative position it should be fine.

Comment: Can you add `fn fix` as well?

Comment: @PitaJ whoops, added. That function handles wrapping. Actually it looks buggy to me, not sure why it's working as that should fail for negatives..

Comment: @PitaJ Figured out what was going on - there was some redundancy, wherever new `Point`s were being created they were calling that `modulo` function I've now edited in. This should reflect the actual behavior.

Comment: I also noticed in your `set_if_2` you only set one region point to the `value`. I imagine you maybe meant to set both in that case?

Comment: @PitaJ Actually that was intentional - `set_if_2` is just an example, but in the real thing I would be setting a single point based on its immediate neighborhood. If I set other parts of the neighborhood, I would want to do so with a lock on *their* neighborhood.

Comment: Okay, so you really only need a write lock on the "target" point?

Comment: @PitaJ Correct. (There's probably no need to maintain the read/write distinction anymore, though - if it's easier for them to just all be write locks, that's fine. The `RwLock` thing is from a previous effort to keep threads from competing - if I get this region thing working, it should no longer be needed.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so I've figured out a couple ways to do this. Both have the same signature of taking a generic number of points, and treating the point at index 0 as the "target" point to write the value to.

1. Without Allocating

This version loops through all points for each region at play, making it `O(R*P)` where `R` is the number of regions and `P` is the number of points.

```rust
fn set_if<const N: usize, F: Fn([T; N]) -> bool>(&self, points: [Point; N], f: F, value: T) -> bool {
    // The region and index within that region for each point
    let point_coords = points.map(|p| self.map_coordinates(p));

    // Extract the target point data for direct usage later
    let (target_region_index, target_index_in_region) = point_coords[0];

    // Iterate through the regions, locking each one,
    // and reading the pre-existing values.
    let mut pre_existing = [None; N];

    // Loop through each region
    let mut region_locks: [_; TOTAL_REGIONS] = std::array::from_fn(|region_index| {
        let mut region = None;

        // Loop through each point
        for (j, (this_region_index, index_in_region)) in point_coords.into_iter().enumerate() {
            // If the point is in this region
            if this_region_index == region_index {
                // Acquire a new lock if necessary
                // (if this is the first point in the region)
                let region = region.get_or_insert_with(|| {
                    self.regions[region_index].write().unwrap()
                });
                // Then read the pre-existing value for this point
                pre_existing[j] = Some(region[index_in_region])
            }
        }

        // Store region locks to hold the lock until we're done
        region
    });

    // Should never fail
    let pre_existing = pre_existing.map(|v| v.unwrap());
    let target_region = region_locks[target_region_index].as_mut().unwrap();

    if f(pre_existing) {
        target_region[target_index_in_region] = value;

        true
    } else {
        false
    }

    // Region locks dropped at end of scope
}
```

2. With Allocating

This version loops through all points once, collecting the points for each region, and then loops through each region with points, obtaining a lock and handling each point in the region.

This makes it `O(R+2P)`.

```rust
fn set_if<const N: usize, F: Fn([T; N]) -> bool>(&self, points: [Point; N], f: F, value: T) -> bool {
    // Store a set of indices for each region
    let mut region_indices: [Vec<(usize, usize)>; TOTAL_REGIONS] = Default::default();

    // Handle the target point first
    let (target_region_index, target_index_in_region) = self.map_coordinates(points[0]);

    region_indices[target_region_index] = vec![
        // We store the index of the point in `points` and
        // the index associated with that point within its region
        (0, target_index_in_region),
    ];

    // Then handle all of the rest
    for (j, p) in points.into_iter().enumerate().skip(1) {
        let (region_index, index_in_region) = self.map_coordinates(p);

        // Store the index of the point within `points` and
        // the index associated with that point within its region
        region_indices[region_index].push((j, index_in_region));
    }

    // Iterate through the regions, locking each one,
    // and reading the pre-existing values.
    let mut pre_existing = [None; N];
    // Store region locks to hold the lock until we're done
    let mut region_locks: [_; TOTAL_REGIONS] = Default::default();

    for (region_index, indices_in_region) in region_indices.into_iter().enumerate() {
        // Skip if there were no points in this region
        if indices_in_region.is_empty() {
            continue;
        };
        
        // Acquire a lock for this region
        let region = self.regions[region_index].write().unwrap();

        // Read the pre-existing value for each point in the region
        for (j, index_in_region) in indices_in_region {
            pre_existing[j] = Some(region[index_in_region]);
        }

        // Store region locks to hold the lock until we're done
        region_locks[region_index] = Some(region);
    }

    // Should never fail
    let pre_existing = pre_existing.map(|v| v.unwrap());
    let target_region = region_locks[target_region_index].as_mut().unwrap();

    if f(pre_existing) {
        target_region[target_index_in_region] = value;

        true
    } else {
        false
    }

    // Region locks dropped at end of scope
}
```

I prefer option #1, because it is simpler and has no allocations. Given you will likely have a small fixed number of regions and points, I expect performance of option 1 to be better as well. If performance is very important, I'd recommend benchmarking both, though.

Comment: I might be missing something, but won't these drop the guards  for everything except `target_region` before the write?

Comment: Yes. Last night I thought that would be a good thing, but on second thought they probably should stick around. Let me add that.

Comment: @EdwardPeters okay should be fixed now

Comment: Okay, I think that works - I'll probably want to adapt it to do some sort of sort over the actually used regions rather than iterate over all of them (that's like, a sort on 4 elements vs. a pass over 100+), but I can work that out myself. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah it may be possible. I assumed that the `f` function has to called with values in the same order as the input points. If that's not required then you can just sort by region index before looping through the points.